# Nix add variadic args to a set from a function

Tags: functional-programming, nix

Is something like this possible in nix?

```
f = {x, y, ...}:
{
    x = x + 1;
    y = y + 2;
    ...;
}
```

where calling `f` on a set of arguments returns a set:

```
f { x = 1; y = 2; }                   -> { x = 2; y = 4; }
f { x = 1; y = 2; z = 5 }             -> { x = 2; y = 4; z = 5; }
f { x = 1; y = 2; z = 5; s = "str"; } -> { x = 2; y = 4; z = 5; s = "str"; }
```

To be clear. The set of ellipsis `...` is the **variadic argument type** and does not mean etcetera used in everyday language. The solution here is to call `get { ... }` on ellipsis if possible. But I don't know if the language supports this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
f = args@{x, y, ...}: args // { x = x + 2; y = y + 2; }
```

You can read more about it here:

https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ss-functions